# Action Button not appearing on Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I've been trying to get an Action Button working on my Android app, and been failing miserably. I've read so many questions and answers and nothing seems to work. The video link always just appears in the menu which I do not want

Here is the menu Xml.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:puertogaleradivesites="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/youtube"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp"
      android:title="YouTube"
      puertogaleradivesites:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      puertogaleradivesites:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="Settings"/>
</menu>
```

And here is the main Java Fragment

```
public class DivesiteFragment extends Fragment {
private Divesite mDivesite;
private TextView mDepthField;
private TextView mSiteDescription;
private TextView mDistance;
private ProportionalImageView mImageView;
public static final String EXTRA_SITE_ID = "com.blueribbondivers.extraSiteID";
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID crimeId = (UUID)getActivity().getIntent()
            .getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_SITE_ID);
    mDivesite = DiveSites.get(getActivity()).getDiveSite(crimeId);
    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    //getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#1c3565\">" + mDivesite.getName() + "</font>"));

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_divesite, parent, false);
    Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
    //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mDepthField = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.divesite_display_depth);
    mDepthField.setText(mDivesite.getMaxDepth());
    mSiteDescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.divesite_display_description);
    mSiteDescription.setText(mDivesite.getSiteDescription());
    mSiteDescription.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    mDistance = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.divesite_display_distance);
    mDistance.setText(mDivesite.getTravelTime());
    mImageView = (ProportionalImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.divesite_display_imageView);
    String imageName = mDivesite.getPhoto();
    final int resourceID = resources.getIdentifier(imageName,"drawable",mContext.getPackageName());
    mImageView.setImageResource(resourceID);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.divesitemenu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
}
```

I have the full project on Github also https://github.com/Jonnyblue/PuertoGaleraDiveSites

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want ? I didn't get ?

Comment: Sorry should of been a bit clearer. The Menu loads as a drop down menu. The YouTube  menu item android:id="@+id/youtube" goes to the settings menu, and doesn't show up as a button, it gets added to the overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying menus like Youtbe, gmail:

You should use **yourapp:showAsAction="always"**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".HomeActivity">
     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_search"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
         yourapp:showAsAction="always"
         android:title="@string/search"/>

     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
         yourapp:showAsAction="always"
         android:title="@string/refresh"/>

 </menu>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: this didn't work for me, not sure if its because of the different fragments. I'm using the holo theme, not sure if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

Your activity extends [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html). If you'd like a backward compatible action bar that works the same on all API levels (things changed significantly in API 21), you should instead extend [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an ActioBar item a as a button but not as an overflow menu, You need to define an `android:orderInCategory` for it. So that it doesn't comes inside the overflow menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_magnify"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/noticiation_count"/>

</menu>
```

Also as you are using fragments its safe to use this line inside the onCreate() method,

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Tested and working perfectly with Fragments.

Comment: Tried this also, deleted my extra settings menu. It still just puts the youtube link in the overflow menu